# Facebook timeline in iOS-App

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview

is it possible to show the Facebook timeline of someone in my iOS application? I don't want to use an `UIWebView`. It should show up in an `UITableView`.

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Facebook SDK for IOS:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios